# Could not find property setter method setAlpha

Tags: java, android, kotlin, objectanimator

This is the Java code for creating an alpha animator object.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 0.5f, 0f);
```

This is the Kotlin code for doing the same.

```
val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 0.5f, 0f)
```

After I converted above Java code to Kotlin, Android Studio is giving me a red error warning with the this message when hover over the line where the error occurs.
**Could not find property setter method setAlpha on java.lang.Void more**

Despite the IDE is giving this error, but I am still able to compile and run it. Any idea why it's giving this error in Kotlin and how to get rid of this error warning?

Comment: Try using `View.ALPHA` instead of `alpha` as a method parameter. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because your `myView` has nullable type, like `View?`.
To get rid of this error convert your view to a non-null type (`myView!!`):

```
val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView!!, "alpha", 0.5f, 0f)
```

Comment: saved my time :)

Comment: Good guess, but it doesn't work in my case.  But the code still compiles with the original error.  Probably another AS/kotlin bug--I'm sure they'll fix it in a few years (right when Google decides to switch to yet another "better" language).